# Load php website into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Hi is there any possibility to load this page to div?

connectis.pl/connectis.pl/index.php

I tryied this way but seems to not load the data.

```
<div id="siteloader"></div>
$("#siteloader").html('<object data="ger-pol.home.pl/connectis.pl/index.php" />');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/

Comment: I would use MrVimes's solution, but your fiddle worked for me (FF)... also with your ger-pol.home.pl-page, [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/1714/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your fiddle and it works just fine..

Might be that you forgot the `script` tag?

```
<script>
$("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://ger-pol.home.pl/connectis.pl/index.php"/>');
</script>
```

Here's [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/1715/)

Answer (score 2):

With jquery you can do it like this...

`$("#siteloader").load("http://ger-pol.home.pl/connectis.pl/index.php");`

**Edit:** Make sure your jquery functions are wrapped in the document ready wrapper...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#siteloader").load("http://ger-pol.home.pl/connectis.pl/index.php");

  });

</script>
```

Or the shorthand...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {

    $("#siteloader").load("http://ger-pol.home.pl/connectis.pl/index.php");

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Is your jquery wrapped in a document ready function?  $(document).ready

Comment: Why load it into an object tag?  I've never seen it done like that.